# Node.js/jade -- How can I pass mysql data as a local variable into inline javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, pug

My Node script has this in it:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection(...);

connection.connect();

connection.query(/*sql query*/, function(err, rows, fields){
  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', { data: JSON.stringify(rows) });
  });
});
```

Then if I do this in my Jade template:

```
body
  p !{data}
```

It displays the data from the MySql query exactly as you'd expect. But if instead I do:

```
body
  script(type='text/javascript').
    console.log(!{data});
```

It gives me `[Object, Object, Object, Object....`

Why is it interpreted differently if it's part of the client Javascript? And how can I fix this?

I put JSON.stringify in the local variable assignment because if I didn't, nothing would get passed through no matter where in the template I tried to put it. Is there another way I'm supposed to be transforming the data maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to give an index like
`console.log(!{data[1]});` to view the objects in console..

Answer (score 0):

I have recently run into this issue like you. I think it would be helpful to point out a few things:

The mysql library from node already returns your data into json. you using stringify returns it as a string; I believe that is why your getting that object back in the console log. try just returning data:rows and accessing the data via dot syntax notation in your template. this is what worked for me.